# C# skipping await method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I publish an event that calls an async method, the event gets published but when it hits the await method it just skips over it and doesn't execute the code, i currently took out the logic and just put in a console.writeline and it doesn't even do that.

so my event gets published

```
eventManager.SyncEvent += EventManager_SyncEventAsync;
```

which calls this method

```
   private async void EventManager_SyncEventAsync(EventData eventData)
   {
        await SyncHousesAsync();//It is Skipping this Line

        IOManager.DisplayToast("Sync", "Synced", context);//and Prints this
   }
```

I just have a print line for the sake of debugging in the async method

```
public async Task SyncHousesAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\nSyncing Houses\n\n\n\n\n");
}
```

Comment: @Sweeper Yes I put a breakpoint in

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so we can be sure there's nothing else going on.

Comment: Common causes of "skipping" are an unhandled exception within the async method (though that doesn't seem to match the code/description here) or source/binary out of sync when debugging. If it's the latter, we can't help but can just recommend cleaning everything to make sure you're debugging the code you think you are.

Comment: It isn't skipping; here's my minimal interpretation from your code - it works fine and outputs "Syncing Houses" as expected: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/f4f09d5c278778cf576c9ef0acc2422e - can you show us a minimal version that *doesn't* behave as expected?

Answer (score 0):

ok so I have solved the problem, What I neglected to mention was this was a xamarin android app.

It turned out the code on the phone was different than the code I was debugging.

I solved the problem by uninstalling app from phone and cleaning and rebuilding.

Thank you all for your help.